# selectfield not loading on build

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am almost giving up. I’ve being trying for almost a month to develop an app using sencha touch  2.2.1 and sencha cmd 3.1.2.324. All works on development, but after create the production file (sencha app build) my selectfield do not load.

Actually I’d isolated all pages on the app and I am working just with few cards. From chrome I can check the webservice is called and return as expected. The console doesn’t show any error, but the selectfield remain empty.

Any clue?

Panel:

```
     Ext.define('MySecondApp.view.Home', {
        extend: 'Ext.Panel',
        xtype: 'mg_home',
        config:
        {
           title:   'Home',
           id:      'tabHome',
           iconCls: 'info',
           layout:  'vbox',
           xtype:   'panel',
           items:
           [
              {docked: 'top',xtype: 'titlebar',title: 'Home'},
              {
                 xtype:         'selectfield',
                 name:          'selectMesHome',
                 id:            'selectMesHome',
                 action:        'selectMesHome',
                 label:         'Mes', /*TODO*/
                 scrollable:    true,
                 displayField:  'dc_data',
                 valueField:    'vl_data',
                 store:         'mesesHome'
              },
              {
                 xtype:         'panel',
                 id:            'home_content',
                 html:          'carregando...'
              }
           ]
        }
     });
```

model:

```
     Ext.define('MySecondApp.model.Meses', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
           fields :
           [
              {name:'dc_data',  type:'string'},
              {name:'vl_data',  type:'string'}
           ]
        }
     });
```

store:

```
     Ext.define('MySecondApp.store.mesesHome', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        storeId: 'mesesHomeStore',
        config: {
           model: 'MySecondApp.model.Meses',
           autoLoad: true,
           proxy:
           {
              type: 'ajax',
              url: 'http://www.meusgastos.com.br/touch/rest/meses.php',
              reader:
              {
                 type: 'json',
                 root: 'data'
              }
           }
        }
     });
```

ajax request some credentials previous saved (and tested, and working). The response will be:

```
     {
         "HEADER": [],
         "vl_atual": "201308",
         "data": [
             {
                 "dc_data": "Agosto/2013",
                 "vl_data": "201308"
             },
             {
                 "dc_data": "Julho/2013",
                 "vl_data": "201307"
             },
             {
                 "dc_data": "Junho/2013",
                 "vl_data": "201306"
             },
             {
                 "dc_data": "Maio/2013",
                 "vl_data": "201305"
             },
             {
                 "dc_data": "Abril/2013",
                 "vl_data": "201304"
             },
             {
                 "dc_data": "Março/2013",
                 "vl_data": "201303"
             }
         ]
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes and try again

**In Store (`MySecondApp.store.mesesHome`)**

1) Put the `storeId` inside config

2) change reader `root` as `rootProperty`

So, store looks like this

```
 Ext.define('MySecondApp.store.mesesHome', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
       storeId: 'mesesHomeStore',
       model: 'MySecondApp.model.Meses',
       autoLoad: true,
       proxy:
       {
          type: 'ajax',
          url: 'http://www.meusgastos.com.br/touch/rest/meses.php',
          reader:
          {
             type: 'json',
             rootProperty: 'data'
          }
       }
    }
 });
```

**In view (`MySecondApp.view.Home`)**

This change is not necessary, But still i suggest you to do this.

Give storeId to store property of selectfield

```
          {
             xtype:         'selectfield',
             name:          'selectMesHome',
             id:            'selectMesHome',
             action:        'selectMesHome',
             label:         'Mes', /*TODO*/
             scrollable:    true,
             displayField:  'dc_data',
             valueField:    'vl_data',
             store:         'mesesHomeStore'
          },
```

Comment: Fastatic! So simple and i was also so far to get it! :) Thanks